# Запуск программы из терминала с перенаправлением ввода из файла, а после ввод с клавиатуры

Tags: linux, поток-ввода, стандартный-ввод-вывод

уважаемые. Язык Паскаль, но хоть дайте понять, куда примерно копать.

Допустим, есть программа A, позволяющая работать с массивом типа string. В ней есть процедуры, позволяющие с ним работать: иниц-я, ввод данных из станд.ввода, вывод, вывод рандомной строки, сортировка и тд.

```
procedure InitStrArray(var s: StringArray);
procedure FillStrArray(var s: StringArray);
...
begin
  InitStrArray(s);
  FillStrArray(s);
  WriteStrArray(s);
```

Я в терминале запускаю конвейером: ./A < text.txt. Строки из текстового файла заносятся в массив и выводятся. Всё гуд.

Далее я решаю из программы A сделать модуль и вставить его в программу B. В программе B я решаю делать те же процедуры: инициализировать и вводить данные + ДОБАВИТЬ бесконечный цикл, где выводится рандомная строка и ожидается ввод пользователя. И допустим дальше с этим уже работать.

```
*здесь модуль A*
begin
  InitStrArray(s);
  FillStrArray(s);
  WriteStrArray(s);
  while true do begin
    writeln(GetRandomString(s));
    read(user_string);
  end;
```

Теперь, если я запускаю конвейером ./B < text.txt, то получается, что я уже не могу вводить данные - они как бы всё ещё берутся из другого потока (text.txt), который на самом-то деле закончился и возвращает пустые строки. Иными словами, я не могу сам с клавиатуры выполнить ввод read(user_string)

**И вопрос такой: как нужно корректно запускать или в ином случае структурировать программу?**

В моем пока скудном представлении есть 2 варианта:

1. Ввод строк самому; имитация конца файла ctrl+d; дохожу до бесконечного цикла и ввожу что угодно, но это лютый тупизм
2. Подключаю файл в самой программе B, читаю строки из файла и передаю процедурам модуля A, заполняя массив; дохожу до бесконечного цикла и ввожу что угодно

Наверняка есть третий вариант, где я всё-таки передаю конвейером в терминале имя текстового файла, из которого я хочу прочитать данные, этот поток ввода закрывается, а потом уже сам с клавиатуры ввожу другие данные, для других целей/переменных и тд.

Comment: Как программа В должна понять, что первая часть входных данных закончилась и началась вторая?

Comment: @ESkri возможно, есть какая-то возможность в нужный момент закончить работу с определенным потоком ввода. Ну неужели если я конвейером перенаправил ввод в программу из файла, то это будет длиться до конца программы?

Comment: `это будет длиться до конца программы?` - у программы только один stdin, и да, он существует "до конца программы".  если вы хотите в него запустить конкатенацию двух потоков (из файла и с клавиатуры), то как программа поймёт где кончился первый и начался второй?

Answer (score 0):

```sh
(cat text.txt; cat) | my_program
```